# Fabricjs: How to break an imported SVG image into separate individual PathGroups rather than one?

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

Overall, I have a rectangular SVG image separated into two halves which I would like to add an image to on click, however, when I import the SVG it creates only one PathGroup rather than two- Does anybody know how I can achieve two distinct PathGroups? I believe this is the first step in achieving my overall goal.

Here's how I'm loading the SVG:

```
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL('./img/rect_w_two_halves.svg', function(objects, options){    
        loadedObject = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        loadedObject.set({
            left:0,
            top:0,
            scaleY:.50,
            scaleX:.50
        });
        canvas.add(loadedObject);
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
```

Here's how the image looks like:

[image]

Here's the SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="320px"
 height="568px" viewBox="0 0 320 568" enable-background="new 0 0 320 568" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_2">
    <line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="15" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="253.978" y1="284" x2="66.022" y2="284"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="15" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M253.04,448.055
    c0,10.338-8.381,18.719-18.719,18.719H85.68c-10.338,0-18.72-8.381-18.72-18.719V119.945c0-10.338,8.382-18.719,18.72-18.719
    h148.642c10.338,0,18.719,8.381,18.719,18.719V448.055L253.04,448.055z"/>
</g></svg>
```

Thanks in advance as I've been really stuck on this issue.

Comment: that svg doesn't render for me when saved as a `.svg` file. Anyhow, why don't you just handcraft your svg file and use that directly: http://caniuse.com/svg About links in svg: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/a-element.html

Comment: Thanks, mb21. According to Fabricjs.com website (http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/ under Path and PathGroup section) it implies that one would want to use Fabric.loadSVGFromURL() to load the entire SVG file rather creating the paths by hand (thought that might be the approach I'll have to take).

Comment: So, basically I ended up going into Adobe Illustrator and using Pathfinder to divide, then upgrouping the shapes (so far, this seems to work albeit not exactly what I want.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add objects from SVG without grouping by passing every element into canvas.add method:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url);

function callback(objects, options) {  
  canvas.add.apply(canvas, objects);
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

There's a [demo](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink) on Fabric.js website, you can find that part at Load SVG tab, "load without grouping" button